# Flutter: Build ListView After http.get Request

Tags: listview, flutter, future

I feel like this problem shouldn't take 6+ hours to figure out yet here I am after much searching and playing around with code. 
 Basically, when I nav to the page, the future automatically sends the http.get request from _getData(). I'm getting the data and building a ListView just fine, the problem is that I want the ListView to only build AFTER a search term has been submitted from the TextField. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class FutureBuilderTestPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  BuilderTestPageState createState() => BuilderTestPageState();
}

class BuilderTestPageState extends State {
  static String _searchTerm = "";
  String _url = "https://api.nal.usda.gov/ndb/search/?format=json&q=$_searchTerm&sort=n&max=20&offset=0&api_key=OMITTEDforThisPost";
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var _futureBuilder = new FutureBuilder(
        future: _getData(),
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
            switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
              case ConnectionState.none:
                return Text('Press button to start.');
              case ConnectionState.active:
              case ConnectionState.waiting:
                return Text('Awaiting result...');
              case ConnectionState.done:
                if (snapshot.hasError) return Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}');
                // return Text('Result: ${snapshot.data}');
                return createMyListView(context, snapshot);
            }
            return null; // unreachable
        });
    return new Scaffold(
        appBar: new AppBar(
          title: Text("Appbar"),
        ),
        body: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Text("Search for food..."),
            TextField(
              decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: 'Search here'),
              onSubmitted: (String valueIn) {
                _searchTerm = valueIn;
              },
            ),
            Text("Results for... " + _searchTerm),
            Divider(height: 4.0),
            Expanded(child: _futureBuilder),
          ],
        ));
  }

  Future<List<dynamic>> _getData() async {
    http.Response response = await http.get(_url,
        headers: {"Accept": "Application/json"});

    final data = jsonDecode(response.body) as Map;
    final mapOfList = data['list'] as Map;
    final listOfItem = mapOfList['item'] as List<dynamic>;

    print(listOfItem.toString());

    var values = new List<dynamic>();
    for (var e in listOfItem) {
      values.add(e);
    }
    return values;
  }

  Widget createMyListView(BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
    List<dynamic> values = snapshot.data;
    return new ListView.builder(
      itemCount: values.length,
      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
        return new Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            new ListTile(
              title: new Text(values[index]['name']),
            )
          ],
        );
      },
    );
  }
}

class FoodObjectFromJson {
  final int offset;
  final String group;
  final String name;
  final int ndbno;
  final String ds;
  final String manu;

  FoodObjectFromJson(
      this.offset, this.group, this.name, this.ndbno, this.ds, this.manu);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question I simplified/modified the code some so a web call is not required.

Note the declaration of bool variable "show_results".  It is key to what you desire to do.  Make sure you note all usages of the variable.

Inside the two setState () constructs it first turns off the visibility/existence of your desired list and then after your search has been performed it turns on the visibility/existence of your desired list.

This code has been tested and works as shown.

Hope this helps.

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class zFutureBuilderTestPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  zBuilderTestPageState createState() => zBuilderTestPageState();
}

class zBuilderTestPageState extends State {
  static String _searchTerm = "";

  bool show_results=false;

  String _url = "https://www.awebsite.com/search.php";
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var _futureBuilder = new FutureBuilder(
        future: _getData(),
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
          switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
            case ConnectionState.none:
              return Text('Press button to start.');
            case ConnectionState.active:
            case ConnectionState.waiting:
              return Text('Awaiting result...');
            case ConnectionState.done:
              if (snapshot.hasError) return Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}');
              // return Text('Result: ${snapshot.data}');
              return createMyListView(context, snapshot);
          }
          return null; // unreachable
        });
    return new Scaffold(
        appBar: new AppBar(
          title: Text("Appbar"),
        ),
        body: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Text("Search for food..."),
            TextField(
              decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: 'Search here'),
              onSubmitted: (String valueIn) => search(valueIn),
            ),
            Text("Results for... " + _searchTerm),
            Divider(height: 4.0),
            show_results == false ? new Container ( width: 0, height: 0 ) : Expanded(child: _futureBuilder),
          ],
        ));
  }

  Future <List<dynamic>> search ( String valueIn ) async {
    print (valueIn);
    setState(() {
      show_results=false;
    });

    List<dynamic> l = await _getData();

    setState(() {
      show_results=true;
    });
    return ( l );
  }

  Future<List<dynamic>> _getData() async {

    List<FoodObjectFromJson> values=new List();
    FoodObjectFromJson H =new FoodObjectFromJson(5,"Orange");
    values.add( H );
    FoodObjectFromJson H2 =new FoodObjectFromJson(8,"Apple");
    values.add( H2 );
    FoodObjectFromJson H3 =new FoodObjectFromJson(22,"Pear");
    values.add( H3 );


    return values;
  }

  Widget createMyListView(BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
    List<dynamic> values = snapshot.data;
    return new ListView.builder(
      itemCount: values.length,
      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
        return new Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            new ListTile(
              title: new Text(values[index].fruit_handle),
            )
          ],
        );
      },
    );
  }
}

class FoodObjectFromJson {
  final int fruit_id;
  final String fruit_handle;

  FoodObjectFromJson(
      this.fruit_id, this.fruit_handle);
}
```

Comment: BTW, it should work basically the same with your http call, it's just that I did not have access to your website search.

Comment: Thank you Mr. Bradford! I like what you did there and it definitely helped out. Now, the behavior is as intended but I'm new to learning state behavior and how to go about manipulating that. That said, the HTTP call still immediately calls when the page is routed to, instead of waiting for search term to be submitted. Then it also calls x4 when it is submitted, and the variable isn't changing within _url i.e. a default search is always returned no matter what String is input. Will be working on this and post when/if I come to a solution. ~Thanks again!